# Увеличение скорости рассылки

Tags: php, daemon

Есть демон написанный на `php`, который выполняет смс рассылку. Для увеличения скорости рассылки я поднимаю на каждую итерацию отдельный `php` процесс, но после мониторинга нагрузки на сервер, сделал выводы что это очень ресурсозатратно, устанавливать расширения типо `pcntl` сейчас уже не совсем уместно, так как функционал уже в продакшн среде. Интересуют примеры по реализациям для подобных задач.

Таким образом поднимаю независимый процесс

```
exec('/usr/bin/php ' . __DIR__  . '/' . $forkProcessName . ' ' . $id . ' > /dev/null &');
```

Comment: [Gearman](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.gearman.php), Redis или любые аналогичные библиотеки для обработки пула задач.

Comment: Наталкивался часто на ReactPhp в интернете, на сколько он может помочь в данной реализации

Comment: Не знаю, возможно никак так как это фреймворк, а не готовая система для создания и выполнения задач.